# How to re-enable text selection on input-field

Tags: css, firefox, selection

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select) the `-moz-user-select`-property on an element will be set on all sub-elements as well. It also states the user-selection can be re-enabled on sub-elements using `-moz-user-select:text`.

I can not get this to work on my input-elements in firefox, but it works in Chrome. Any idea on how to fix this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NBNpF/3/ (Try to put focus in the input-box, it only works in Chrome, not Firefox). I am using FireFox 18.0.2

Comment: i cant understand the issue here, what i see is its working in FF and not working in chrome, becasue dive with class `unselectable`, so was unable to select it in FF but i can in chrome when i changed it  `selectable` select working again in ff.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: On my computer it is only possible to select the text in the input-field in Chrome, not in FF. Is it the other way around for you?

Comment: I had the same as @Espo.

Comment: @Espo oh i see, sorry was in misunderstanding, yes I have same issue now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution I think, the key was to replace `-moz-user-select: none;` with `-moz-user-select: -moz-none;` instead.

so Your CSS must be like :

```
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

I updated your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NBNpF/7/

I Hope this help.